# Pulling out distribution values Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution

Given the example on the website:

```
r = normrnd(10,1,100,1);
histfit(r,6)
```

For the fitted distribution is it possible to pull out the values on that distribution (assume here that the numbers will not always be normally distributed)? i.e. is it possible to get values for the fitted function or the columns of the histogram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `histfit` code, you'll see it calls `fitdist` to fit the distribution. So, you can get the parameters (mu and sigma) of the fitted distribution by

```
pd = fitdist(r,'normal');
mu = pd.mu;
sigma = pd.sigma;
```

To obtain values of this pdf, say at points `x`, use

```
y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
```

Comment: if you have a dataset like x =[1 1 2 2 2 3] and plot for values [1 2 3] (simple enough), the result looks way different from the histfit implemented on the same x dataset.

Comment: @Ams It's just a different normalization. `normpdf` gives the true pdf (normalized to area 1). `histfit` plots the pdf scaled so that its area matches that of the histogram. You can see this in `histfit`'s code (lines 86--89 in R2017b)